# How to reshape data frame out of rows and conditional on the values

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new in R and I guess this should be easy to do. I have a large data, where for each group in every period there might be two or three variable to estimate. The data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
 group    = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 period   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
 term     = c("Inv", "Not", "Clue", "Mix", "Clue"),
 estimate = c(-1.2, -.85, -.35, -1, -.6),
 pvalue   = c(.001, .01, .00001, .0001, 001)
)

  group period term estimate pvalue
1     1      1  Inv    -1.20  1e-03
2     1      1  Not    -0.85  1e-02
3     1      1 Clue    -0.35  1e-05
4     1      2  Mix    -1.00  1e-04
5     1      2 Clue    -0.60  1e+00
```

Now I need to summerasie all information in one line for every round of each group. It needs to be in a way that rows spread over columns mentioning their estimate if it exists, and NaN if it does not. It looks like this:

```
newdf <- data_frame(
 group         = c(1, 1),
 period        = c(1, 2),
 Inv.estimate  = c(-1.2, NaN),
 Not.estimate  = c(-.85, NaN),
 Clue.estimate = c(-.35, -.6),
 Mix.estimate  = c(NaN, -1),
 Inv.pvalue    = c(.001, NaN),
 Not.pvalue    = c(.01, NaN),
 Clue.pvalue   = c(.00001, .001),
 Mix.pvalue    = c(NaN, .001)
)

  group period Inv.estimate Not.estimate Clue.estimate Mix.estimate Inv.pvalue Not.pvalue Clue.pvalue
1     1      1         -1.2        -0.85         -0.35          NaN      0.001       0.01       1e-05
2     1      2          NaN          NaN         -0.60           -1        NaN        NaN       1e-03
  Mix.pvalue
1        NaN
2      0.001
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the `dplyr` method, we could also use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`) and use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), group+period~term, 
         value.var= c("estimate", "pvalue"), sep=".")
#      group period estimate.Clue estimate.Inv estimate.Mix estimate.Not pvalue.Clue pvalue.Inv pvalue.Mix pvalue.Not
#1:     1      1         -0.35         -1.2           NA        -0.85     0.00001      0.001         NA       0.01
#2:     1      2         -0.60           NA           -1           NA     1.00000         NA     0.0001         NA
```

Comment: Good to know that the `value.var` feature. Lots to catch up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dplyr and tidyr packages for this. First, I used `gather()` to put the data in a long format. You have the values of estimate and pvalue in one column. You also have the two variable names in one column, which I named `foo`. Then, I used `mutate()` to create column names as you indicated. I remove term and foo since they are no longer necessary. Finally, I used `spread()` to reshape the data into a wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(df, foo, value, -c(group, period, term)) %>%
mutate(whatever = paste(term, foo, sep = ".")) %>%
select(-term, -foo) %>%
spread(whatever, value)

  group period Clue.estimate Clue.pvalue Inv.estimate Inv.pvalue Mix.estimate Mix.pvalue Not.estimate
1     1      1         -0.35       1e-05         -1.2      0.001           NA         NA        -0.85
2     1      2         -0.60       1e+00           NA         NA           -1      1e-04           NA
  Not.pvalue
1       0.01
2         NA
```